# Goat just gave birth and I'm worried

Tags: goats

My pygmy goat gave birth about 2 to 3 hours ago. She has passed her afterbirth but she is still having contractions and discharge again and she won't let us touch her because she has always been scared of people since we got her! I'm very worried about her. Could she still have a baby inside? What else could be causing this? This is our first time with a delivery and I don't want anything to happen to her!

Comment: You need to consult with someone that has been through this process before, it's too hard for people on the internet to direct you without knowing more about the animal, and even then, you don't know what kind of advice you are going to get.

Comment: This sounds like a "call your vet" situation.

Comment: i was just trying to find someone who has been through this and would know what could be going on but thank you anyways i thought i could get help here and some answers that might would help

Comment: my vet is closed just talked to my aunt and she said its normal she has had goats before !

Comment: In a day or two when things calm down, can you do some research and provide an authoritative answer with good references to your question. In this way a good answer will be available here when someone else comes looking.

Comment: More detail needed "[Postpartum: Cramping will be most intense during the first day or two after giving birth and should taper off on the third day or so (though it can take six weeks or longer for uterus to return to normal size)."](http://www.babycenter.com/0_postpartum-cramps-afterpains_11723.bc) There insufficient detail in the question to define if there is a medical emergency or if the uterus is recovering normally. Key points required to have make a suggestion would, be the age of the mother, is this her first or umpteenth birth? Does she usually have twins, or do twins run in her line.